# Application exception issue

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, exception, ambiguous

I can't run my application. What can I do to fix this issue?

I'm using Net 3.5 for this project

I get this exception:

"Ambiguous type reference. A type named 'TypeExtension' occurs in at least two namespaces, 'System.Windows.Markup' and 'System.Windows.Markup'. Consider adjusting the assembly XmlnsDefinition attributes."

```
<Window x:Name="testing" x:Class="testing.MainWindow"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfTool="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
        Title="testing" Height="539" Width="694.745" Icon="Resources/microsoft.ico" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
</Window>
```

Comment: @DJKRAZE
I have WPF version 3.0.6920.4902

Comment: What version of VS are you using 2008 or 2010, was this something that you are migrating from an older version. sounds like you will need to search for all references that use Markup and fully qualify the namespace to resolve your issue

Comment: I'm Using Visual Studio 2012 latest service pack

Comment: have you tried doing the project as a .net 4.0 project instead of 3.5 also are you sure that version is compatible with VS2012

Comment: @DJKRAZE
WPF extended Toolkit is compatible with 3.5...
I want it to use 3.5 because of OS compatibility. (is going to be used on multiple computers)

Comment: then you need to make sure the rest of the assemblies that you are referencing in your projects are .net 3.5 compatible

Comment: @DJKRAZE 
How do I do that?

Comment: Do you have like a yellow triangle when you look at the `references` node in the project? if so remove the reference and try to reload the assembly again

Comment: No, Every reference is the original ones you get when you start a new project.

Only default + WPF extended toolkit references.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestions:

1. Close your solution, delete all your BIN-folders in your solution. And reopen en rebuild again.
2. Check all the references of your projects. Do all projects refer to the same `System.Windows.Markup`? Or does one project refer to another version than another project?
3. Make sure all of your projects are targeting the same .NET Fx version. (In your case: 3.5)
4. Make sure all references from your projects are targeting DLL's of the correct version.

If this does not help:

- Remove all references and compile. You get a lot of errors. Fix one or two errors by added a correct reference. Compile again, etc. etc. During this proces you eliminate the references you might not need anymore. You probably have a reference to an old dll which has been replaced by a new dll with a different name. This can happen after an upgrade of your Visual Studio or other software.

Comment: I have System.Windows.Markup
in 3 references.
Member of PresentationFramework
Member of WindowsBase
Member of PresentationCore

Comment: The odd thing is... The type named 'TypeExtension' Is only shown In the PresentationFramework...

Comment: How many projects are in your solution? And are all projects targeting .NET Fx 3.5?

Comment: Are you using any 3rd-party libraries, like Infragistics?

Comment: 1 Project.
I'm using WPF Toolkit Extended.
How can I look if every project is targeting 3.5?I started it as 3.5

Comment: I modified my answer. I added suggestion 3 till 5.

Comment: To find out which target your project is running: rightclick on your project file and choose Properties. I think it is the first tab. To find out which references you are having, select a references and see the properties-window.

Comment: Took a deeper look and Inner exception tells this : {"An item with the same key has already been added."}

On line 1.

Comment: Every reference is atleast 3.5. The highest was : WPFToolkit = 3.5.40128.1

The rest is 3.5 and 2.0.0.0

All runtime versions is : v2.0.50727

Comment: Do you have a reference to `Draft.PresentationDesignMarkup`?

Comment: Used Search function In reference tab and no hits on PresentationDesignMarkup

Closest I had was : System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterResolutionKind

The issue comes from presentationFramework it seems.

Comment: I am at a loss... It is 3:13 AM here... middle of the night. I am going to bed. Tomorrow I will take a fresh look at it.

Comment: Thank you for helping me.
See you later!
Same Time here. 3:14.